# How to get(extract) the values data parameter from the canvas page url after getting the Requests_ids

Tags: url, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-canvas

I am able to get the value of Requests_ids by following way  `$requestid=$_GET['request_ids'];` .

But I am unable to get the value of data variable   which I passed to url like following  way

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
        message: ms,
        max_recipients: 1,

        title: 'loveeeeeeeeee',
        new_style_message: true,           

        data: "Any value passed here" //I am passing few values to canvas page URL. 
    }, requestCallback);
```

How can i get this data values? Plz help me or suggest any other approach to pass the variables to canvas page url?

Comment: You have to read the request object instance from the API to get the `data` value. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/requests/

Comment: @CBroe  I have throughly read it.but there is not any refrence to get the data values.I will much  owe to you,if you you code this in Answer setion.

Comment: The Request Dialog docs say about the `data` parameter, _“This will be stored as part of the request objects created.”_ And how to read those request objects is described on the page I linked. So do so, and log the request object to the console, then you’ll see what info it contains.

Answer (score 0):

In your handler, you have to call back into the facebook graph API like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<request_id>?access_token=<app_token>
```

The call takes one of the request_ids passed in the http query, and also an access token. The json document that is returned contains the value you passed for the data param.

This question is similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10310915/497357) and my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22416355/497357) with some code may help.