# Access facebook canvas URL parameters from my app

Tags: javascript, facebook-canvas

I'm making a facebook canvas app (a game) and I want my players to use links with url parameters that link to different areas in the game, i.e.

https://apps.facebook.com/mgatlandtestapp?level=emeraldhillzone

How do I access the *level=emeraldhillzone* information in my app (either client-side with javascript in an iFrame, or server-side as a node.js application)

---

Things I've tried so far:

1. This [4-year-old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10819337/439948) says it's possible to in the client-side code but doesn't say how (sorry if I'm missing something obvious! window.location gives the location of my heroku server, not the facebook url.)
2. Some of the [facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request) made me think this would work:

> Use a url in the form https://apps.facebook.com/mgatlandtestapp?app_data=yourDataHere then *on the server side* get the signed request sent to the server and it will contain an app_data field.

However when I did this, the signed request did not contain an app_data field.

After reading more, I think the app_data thing only works if the app is being loaded within a facebook Page Tab, not a facebook Canvas Page.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook sends an initial POST to your app, which includes the url parameters. You can access the url parameters from in that POST request.

I used this url to load the page:

`https://apps.facebook.com/mgatlandtest/?level=emeraldhillzone`

I used this code in my node.js server app to serve the request

```
app.post('/*', function(request, response) {
  console.log('url parameters:');
  console.log(request.query);
  response.redirect('/');
});
```

The output in the node console was:

> url parameters:
>   { level: 'emeraldhillzone' }

You could then use the parameters to redirect to a different page.

---

This was actually really simple, once I got past all the distracting misinformation. The key was searching for 'deep linking' (instead of 'url parameters'), which brought up [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812891/how-to-deep-link-to-a-facebook-app-not-page-tab)